# How to display node.js locals in vash views (UPDATE)

Tags: javascript, node.js, vash

What I am trying to do:

Using middleware function I want to store user data from session in to locals so I can use it later in my views without store those data in every method / controller.

**Instead of (in every method / controller):**

```
function(req, res){
    data.user = req.session.user;
    res.render('someView', data);
}
```

and in View (template):

```
<div>
  @model.user.username
</div>
```

**i want to define middleware like this:**

```
if (req.session.user) {
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    var data = req.session.user;
    var timeout = data.loggedIn + config.auth.timeout;
    if (timeout < now) {
        req.session.user = null;
        reg.flash('errors', {
            param: 'default',
            msg: 'Your session is expired...'
        });
        return res.redirect('/login');
    }
    res.locals.user = sesData;
}
return next();
```

and in view display my data from res.locals. And there is my BIG questionmark... is it possible ?

I could find any information how to display data from res.locals in **vash** views.

Am i missing something, is my solution plausible ?

**UPDATE**

Finally i found solution. Displaying app.locals in VASH views is quite simple :-)

**View:**

```
<div>
    @model._locals.user.username
</div>
```

would do what i need :-)

I hope someone will find it useful.

Comment: I don't think that the middleware can communicate with a view. But it's maybe possible to `bind` some values to all views, I don't know. I had the same problem and I solved it by a sort of `__before` method that bind this kind of data to all views using sails.js framework.

Comment: As far as i know JADE and EJS supports it...

Comment: it works for "res.locals" but do you know how to access to "app.locals"?